# el cron es ejecutado varias veces por varios usuarios

Tags: linux, debian, raspberry-pi, cron

tengo varios CRON en una raspberry pi y me he dado cuenta que se ejecutan mas de una vez, sobre todo uno que se debe ejecutar cada 5 minutos pero lo hace 3 veces, hice que escribiera el usuario que ejecuto ese archivo con un nombre aleatorio para que no se borre la evidencia y lo ejecuta PI, ROOT y www-data.

como puedo prevenir que sea ejecutado tantas veces?

abajo tengo los CRON

```
0 22 * * * rm /var/www/html/session/ses* >/dev/null 2>&1 # JOB_ID_6
*/10 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/reparaMarcas.php >/dev/null 2>&1 # JOB_$
*/5 * * * * /opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp > /var/www/html/temperatura.txt >$
*/30 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/hotreboot.php >/dev/null 2>&1 # JOB_ID_$
0 22 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/ADM_AUTOMAIL.php >/dev/null 2>&1 # JOB_ID$
0 21 * * * sudo reboot >/dev/null 2>&1 # JOB_ID_13
0 5 * * * php /var/www/html/ADM_UPDATE.php >/dev/null 2>&1 # JOB_ID_15
*/5 * * * * php /var/www/html/checkStatus.php >/dev/null 2>&1 # JOB_ID_14
```

Comment: ¿Cómo sacaste la lista de los crons? Seguramente el cron de otros usuarios también tiene entradas

Answer (score 0):

En vez de ejecutar php directamente en el cron, crea un script y dentro ejecuta la linea que tu quieras. Pero justo antes comprueba que está corriendo, si lo está, que no lo ejecute y si lo está que si.

Algo así:

```
EJECUCION=`ps -ef |grep reparaMarcas.php|wc -l`  # 
if [ $($EJECUCION) = 1 ]; then  
 /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/reparaMarcas.php
fi
```

Al hacer un ps -ef, sale lo que está ejecutándose y mas el propio grep que haces, con lo que si hay mas de 1 linea, es que está ejecutándose.